# Unable to find element in IE but in FF it works fine

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**EDIT:**

my CSSSelector is like this: (which is working fine in FF)

```
for (int i = 1; i < _count; i++)
{
    ..................
    ..................
    div#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1 table.gv tbody tr.item:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-of-type(3)
    ..................

}
```

**EDIT END**

I'm using Selenium 2.29 and IE (8) and FF (17.1)
in FF all my test cases passed and when I run in IE majority of my test cases failed and here is the error message:

```
Test method threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to find element with css selector ==
```

div#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1 table.gv tbody tr.item:nth-child(1) > td:nth-of-type(3)

I'm using CSSSelector.

do I have to change the CSSSelector for IE to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38

IE8 and below don't support the `:nth` selectors.

Comment: so what is the solution to my question?

Comment: Change your CSS selector to some other value, or use XPath. Or inject Sizzle to use that for CSS instead of native CSS support.

Answer (score 0):

CSS nth-of-type is not supported in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Since IE8 doesn't support :nth selectors try injecting Sizzle. Sizzle (the selector engine jQuery uses) comes with a built-in `:nth-child()` selector, but lacks an `:nth-of-type()` selector.  Try replacing your `:nth-of-type` with `:nth-child`